# How to setup Testcontainers with a SQLite database?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, entity-framework, testcontainers

I'm looking for an example of how to use [Testcontainers for .NET](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/) with a SQLite database. I've tried the following based on the example here (https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/api/create_docker_container/) :

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task TestContainerSetup()
{
    const ushort HttpPort = 80;

    var sqliteContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
        .WithName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"))
        .WithImage("keinos/sqlite3:latest") // https://hub.docker.com/r/keinos/sqlite3
        //.WithCommand("sqlite3 --version")
        .WithPortBinding(HttpPort, true)
        .Build();

    await sqliteContainer.StartAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new UriBuilder("http", sqliteContainer.Hostname, sqliteContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(HttpPort)).Uri;

    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Empty)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, httpResponseMessage.StatusCode);
}
```

Unfortunately the `await sqliteContainer.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` times out and I am kinda lost on how to continue.

Comment: Not an answer - but personally I would just start in-memory instance of SQLite and do not bother with containers at all. I would argue that is one of the reasons to use SQLite - that it is lightweight and does not need installation.

Comment: Fair point, this is what I've done already but I'm constantly running into flaky tests due to everything being in memory and tests failing when running as a batch. I'm developing a Docker container that uses Sqlite in production and figure I could have more stable tests by spinning up the real deal.

Comment: This is an interesting behaviour, I have a quite big project with quite a lot of tests doing exactly that and we have not seen the flaky tests due to in-memory SQLite. Also it is pretty fine to use file based version (just do not share the file, create a separate one for each test and clean up afterwards).

Comment: That is a really great suggestion! I realize I'm over complicating this and a simple SQLite file for each test as you mentioned is most likely the best approach here. I will try that first and if that still causes the flaky tests then the problem must be somewhere else. Thank you very much!

Comment: AFAIK the same can be done with in-memory approach, do not have example right now but based on [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#sharedmemdb) something like this connection string should work: `file:some_guid_here?mode=memory&cache=shared`

Comment: If you are seeing some flakiness, I think this is related to test pollution. While you can solve test pollution with a new-container-per-test approach, it is generally not recommended from the Testcontainers side, since it can substantially decrease the performance of your test suite. Try to write idempotent tests.

Comment: I do not think the Docker image does what you expected. It does **not** initiate a hosted SQLite instance, nor an HTTP back-end. Instead, the image exits immediately. From my understanding, the image only offers SQLite access from a Docker instance, but does not function as a hosted database service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that there is no need for the test containers here, just use unique SQLite connection string per test, either in file mode using different files or the same via in-memory connection strings. Based on [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) for in-memory connection string following should work:

```cs
var connectionString = $"file:{Guid.NewGuid()}?mode=memory?cache=shared";
```

Or just `":memory:"` but be sure not to share the connection between tests:

> When this is done, no disk file is opened. Instead, a new database is created purely in memory. The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed. Every :memory: database is distinct from every other. So, opening two database connections each with the filename ":memory:" will create two independent in-memory databases.

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the better approach as using TestContainers for SQLite is overkill